# Ionic 2 Angularfire 2 retrieve collection from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm developing a mobile app using Ionic 2, Angularfire 2 and Firebase, but I'm stuck, this is my Firebase data structure:

[image]

I need to create a list from `carrito`, but at the same time I need to get the `precio` field and link it to another collection - `precios`, and get with the key value (as shown in the image above), the fields related (opcion & precio).

The code : list.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
   selector: 'page-lista',
   templateUrl: 'lista.html',
 })
 export class Lista {
    public restaName:any;
    serviceData: string; 

    carrito: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
    precios: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:
    NavParams, af: AngularFire, private shareService: ShareService) {

    this.serviceData = shareService.getRestaName();
    this.restaName = this.serviceData

    this.carrito = af.database.list('/carrito', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'restaname',
        equalTo: this.restaName
      }
    });
     this.precios = af.database.list('/precios', {
      query: {
        orderByKey: true,
        equalTo: this.precio  ???? ---> HERE BEGIN MY DOUBTS
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is part of lista.html

```
<ion-content padding>
 <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let item of carrito | async ">
     <p> {{item.prodname}} - {{item.cantidad}}</p>
   </ion-item>  
   <ion-item *ngFor="let precio of precios | async "> ??? HOW CAN I GET THE FIELDS precio and opcion
     <p>${{precio.precio}}</p>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Any tips or comments will be appreciated !

Comment: Provide code please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Array of FirebaseObjectObservable instead of 
`precios: FirebaseListObservable<any>;`

```
public precios :Array<FirebaseObjectObservable<any>>
this.carrito.subscribe(carrito => carrito.forEach(singleCarrito=>
precios.push(af.database.object('/precios/'+singleCarrito.precio))
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you for your tip.  I'm getting a error message : Generic type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).  Import FirebaseObjectObservable, and I already importing. Any idea ?

Comment: My fault, I made a little mistake in my example. I'll corect it in my answer.